# React-routing config issue to change new home page

Tags: react-router

I am new to react-router.

In current app we are using below react-router

```
module.exports = (
  <Router history={HashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Frame}>
        <IndexRoute component={Page1} />
        <Route path="all" component={Page2} />
        <Route path="admin" component={Page3} />
        <Route path="proxy" component={Page4} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

due to some changes now I want to make different page as home page but also want to make minimum changes to unimpact the current functionalities. Using the below router config but not working

```
  <Router history={HashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
        <Route path="achieve" component={Frame}>
            <Route path ="achieve" component={Page1}>
            <Route path="all" component={Page2} />
            <Route path="admin" component={Page3} />
            <Route path="proxy" component={Page4} />
        </Route>            
    </Route>
   </Route>
  </Router>
```

Any pointer to resolve the issues and to explore this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to make each page as a home page then don't use nested route, make the separate route for each.
Try this:

```
<Router history={HashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/achieve" component={Frame}/>
    <Route path ="/achieve" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="/all" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Page3} />
    <Route path="/proxy" component={Page4} />
</Router>
```

Use nesting in that route where you want to use some component inside that. Lets say you want to use some component inside admin page then :

```
 <Router history={HashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/achieve" component={Frame}/>
    <Route path ="/achieve" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="/all" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Page3} >
       <IndexRoute component={comp1}/>                      
       <Route path="/xyz" component={comp2}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/proxy" component={Page4} />
</Router>
```

Follow these links for better explanation:

https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669#.sjzpetwbb

*Please comment if need any help.*

Comment: Thanks @mayank-shukla ... It worked out for me. Thanks a lot.